# SSLException when trying to read the content of HttpResponse

Tags: httpresponse, github-api, apache-commons-httpclient, sslexception

I'm implementing an application that communicates with the GitHub API in order to infer some statistics about projects developed currently. I chose to make the requests asynchronously, using `HttpAsyncClient`.

My problem is that after I execute all requests and get all the responses from the API (around 150 of them) and I try to read the content with

```
String content = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

I'm getting following SSLException after ~120 responses read:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:557)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:509)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:883)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:840)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:94)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:204)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:182)
at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:138)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:282)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:324)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:176)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:224)
at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:264)
at pl.xsolve.githubmetrics.github.OwnGitHubClient.extractBodyFromResponse(OwnGitHubClient.java:117)
```

The problem disappears when I decrease the number of requests significantly (for instance, by half). Also, all the responses contain `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` - I've checked it with `response.getStatusLine()` and it works until the very end of the response list.
The problem persists even if I remove `httpClient.shutdown()` in the `finally` block (which is executed before reading the content).

From the stack trace, I've concluded that the exception is thrown on the line

```
while((l = reader.read(tmp)) != -1)
```

Is the entity in the `HttpResponse` getting somehow outdated? Do you see an error in my reasoning? What can be the reason why first 120 responses are parsed properly and then SSLException is thrown?

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

This could also be dependent upon your version of openssl. On a python project I maintain, we've seen errors in openssl 0.9.8 when people make large numbers of SSL requests in a short period of time. Admittedly it was nothing like your error message, but upgrading to openssl 1.0 might help.